# How can I avoid mangling arguments with spaces in Exim's ${run{...}} expansion?

Tags: configuration, exim

I have a program, `/usr/local/bin/rt_queue_exists`, which takes one argument. If the argument smells good, the program exits with status 0; non-zero otherwise. I want a router that accepts messages only if the local part smells good, according to this program.

Further, this program relies on a configuration file which is readable only by root and www-data, so I thought I'd configure sudo to allow `rt_queue_exists` to be invoked as www-data by Exim.

Thus, I came up with this in my router options:

```
condition = ${run{/usr/bin/sudo -u www-data /usr/local/bin/rt_queue_exists $local_part}{yes}{no}}
```

It works, usually, except when there's a space in the local part ([yes that's allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6.1)). When there's a space in the local part, `rt_queue_exists` is invoked with *two* arguments.

This is bad because:

- some of my queue names have spaces in them
- if I can alter the command with spaces, can I perform more serious injection attacks?

There is a similar problem in bash:

```
cat $file   # BAD! NO!
cat "$file" # good!
```

What's the analogous solution in exim?

Comment: Through experimentation, it seems that `$local_part` can go in quotes, so the solution for exim is essentially the same as it is for bash. However, I can't find any description of this functionality in the Exim manual, which would be necessary to really understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a direct solution to your problem, I avoid exim, It is a general solution for the class of problems of sending characters which are handled specially through a data channel that is not eight bit clean, without triggering the special meanings in the data channel.

Encode all special characters. In this case the character that is giving you trouble is space with a value of 0x20, so you can either create a special purpose encoding, or find a stock encoding that will just work. I would recommend url encoding because it is simple, well documented, designed for dealing with a similar class of problems (CGI), has multiple readily available implementations, and a simple subset which will catch the observed problem can be implemented with the regular expressions that come with bash. for a quick summary of url encoding, all characters that give problems are replaced with a three character string consisting of `%` (0x25) followed by the two hex characters of the value that would otherwise give problems. for example if we had the string "eat $%!&" the two characters that would give trouble are the space and the percent, so after encoding we would have "eat%20$%35!&" which has no spaces for exim to choke on. we thin reverse the process on the other side, to get back the original string. I have included the following two sed scripts to encode and decode the string handling only the two special characters mentioned.

```
s/%/%35/g
s/ /%20/g

s/%20/ /g
s/%35/%/g
```

note that during encoding the percent was encoded first, and that during decoding it was decoded last.